# Bulk operation in csv files and saving it in different name

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to read 25 csv files which is contained in a folder(eg: D:\Data\Data\Data*.csv).
  Reading each file and replacing sequence of characters.
eg:

```
Replace " with null , 

Replace \, with - ,
Replace \" with ' ,
Replace \N with null ,
Replace , with tab.
```

After performing series of replacement, i need to save it in previous folder (eg: D:\Data\Data*.csv).

single file piped together worked well.

```
(Get-Content D:\Data\Data\Data\csv1.csv)|%{$_-replace'"',""}|out-file -FilePath D:\Data\Data\csv1.csv -Force -Encoding ascii.
```

I also tried with `(backtick) after each -replace. but its throwing error. I am not sure with clubbing various replacement.

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Harish

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .Replace() method instead you can chain them, like:

```
ForEach($File in (GCI "D:\Data\Data\Data*.csv"){
    $File|%{$_.Replace('"',$null).Replace("\,","-").Replace('\"',"'").Replace("`\N",$null).Replace(",","`t")}|Out-File "D:\Data\$($File.Name)" -force -encoding ascii
}
```